# Mostrar elementos en una tabla - Angular

Tags: angular, get, table

Tengo una API de la cual necesito traer dos JSON, y el importante es esta:

**Relaciones**:

```
  {
    "id": 0,
    "source": {
      "id": 0
    },
    "target": {
      "id": 0
    },
    "type": 0
  }
```

La otra trae unos eventos con sus etiquetas, y de ellas necesito el nombre y el ID.

El JSON de las relaciones tiene un `source ID` y un `target ID` y un `type`. Y se utiliza para crear relaciones entre eventos.

Para poner un ejemplo: digamos que tengo dos eventos con **ID 1** y **ID 2** y quiero crear una relación entre ellos, pues en `source ID` **agrego el ID 1** y en `target ID`  **agrego el ID 2** y le añado un **tipo (1, 2 o 3)**. Y con esto tendría una relación entre el evento 1 con el evento 2.

Ahora, tengo una tabla como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde la cabecera de las columnas deben de ser el numero total de eventos, en este caso hay 3 eventos. Y en las filas lo mismo. Digamos que es una tabla de n x n eventos.

La idea es una matriz donde por ejemplo, el **evento de prueba 2** tiene una relación con el **evento de prueba 1** y solo con el. Pues en esa fila debería de aparecer un `1 - -`. El guion significa que no hay nada, y el 1 el tipo de relación.

Para obtener una lista de relaciones tengo el siguiente metodo:

```
  private getRelaciones(idRevision){
    this.relacionService.getRelaciones(idRevision).subscribe(
      (data:any) => {
        this.relaciones = data;
        console.log(this.relaciones);
      }
    );
  }
```

Y el data lo estoy almacenando aquí: `relaciones: any[] = [];`

El método lo llamo en el `ngOnInit`: `this.getRelaciones(this.idRevision);`

El método de la llamada a la API la tengo en una clase Service:

```
  getRelaciones(idRevision: string){
    return this.http.get(`${this.URL}/relation?revisionId=${idRevision}`,this.OPCIONES);
  }
```

Pero no consigo mostrar los datos de esa forma, y llevo muchas horas con esto.

Así tengo la tabla ahora mismo:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"></th>
            <th *ngFor="let evento of eventos" scope="col">{{evento['name']}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody *ngFor="let evento of eventos">
        <tr>
            <td><b>{{evento['name']}}</b></td>
            <td *ngFor="let relacion of relaciones">{{relacion['type']}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Pero me muestra los valores repetidos en cada fila. Antes tenia comprobaciones muy liosas, y llevo borrando y editando código un día entero. **¿Alguna forma de hacerlo?**

**EDITO 07/09**

**Aplicando la respuesta de Legna:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th *ngFor="let evento of eventos" scope="col">{{evento['name']}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let relacion of relaciones">
            <th scope="row">{{getNameEvent(relacion['source']['id'])}}</th>
            <td *ngFor="let evento of eventos">
                {{evento['id'] === relacion['target']['id'] ? relacion['type'] : "--" }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Cambiando el orden de cada iteración he logrado hacer funcionar una buena parte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien las cabeceras se muestran como se deben de mostrar, y el contenido de cada celda se ajusta perfecto. Pero tengo el problema: como se ve en la imagen, el **evento de prueba 2** tiene 2 relaciones, pero se ve por duplicado. Tendría que verse una única fila con su tipo de relación. **¿Como soluciono esto?**

**Evento:**

```
  {
    "id": 0,
    "code": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "image": "string",
    "category": 0,
    "revision": {
      "id": 0
    }
  }
```

Así cargo la lista de eventos desde la API, en el `ngOnInit`:

```
  private cargarEventos(idRevision: string){
    this.eventoService.getEventos(idRevision).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.eventos = data;
      }
    );
  }
```

Para obtener una lista de eventos es necesario pasarle por parámametro un ID de una revisión, pero no hay que fijarse en esto.

Como te he comentado en la respuesta, una relación esta compuesta por dos ID de eventos ( `source` y `target` ) y un tipo.

**Datos reales:**

DATOS DE LOS EVENTOS:

```
[ {
    "id": 1,
    "code": "code-007",
    "name": "Evento ejemplo 1",
    "description": "Descripcion cualquiera...",
    "image": "no-img",
    "category": 7
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "code-016",
    "name": "Evento ejemplo 2",
    "description": "Descripcion cualquiera...",
    "image": "no-img",
    "category": 10
  },
    {
    "id": 3,
    "code": "code-021",
    "name": "Evento ejemplo 3",
    "description": "Descripcion cualquiera...",
    "image": "no-img",
    "category": 3
  },
    {
    "id": 4,
    "code": "code-089",
    "name": "Evento ejemplo 4",
    "description": "Descripcion cualquiera...",
    "image": "no-img",
    "category": 12
  },
    {
    "id": 5,
    "code": "code-0227",
    "name": "Evento ejemplo 5",
    "description": "Descripcion cualquiera...",
    "image": "no-img",
    "category": 1
  },
    {
    "id": 6,
    "code": "code-007",
    "name": "Evento ejemplo 6",
    "description": "Descripcion cualquiera...",
    "image": "no-img",
    "category": 10
  },
    {
    "id": 7,
    "code": "code-097",
    "name": "Evento ejemplo 7",
    "description": "Descripcion cualquiera...",
    "image": "no-img",
    "category": 80
  }
]
```

DATOS DE LAS RELACIONES:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "source": {
      "id": 1
    },
    "target": {
      "id": 2
    },
    "type": 2
  },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "source": {
      "id": 2
    },
    "target": {
      "id": 4
    },
    "type": 1
  },
    {
    "id": 3,
    "source": {
      "id": 1
    },
    "target": {
      "id": 5
    },
    "type": 3
  },
    {
    "id": 4,
    "source": {
      "id": 5
    },
    "target": {
      "id": 6
    },
    "type": 0
  }
]
```

Te dejo una **lista de 7 eventos y 4 relaciones** como si me llegaran de la API, eso son los datos que tengo acceso para mostrar. Debo de mostrar como cabeceras el nombre de cada evento, tanto en filas como en columnas. Por lo tanto seria una **tabla de 7x7** en este caso.

Comment: creo que necesitas explicar un poco más lo de las relaciones, eso no se entiende

Comment: ¿Que no esta claro? Y edito con mas claridad

Comment: como generas las relaciones, eso confunde un poco. Creo que todo lo puedes resolver antes de presentar en el frontend.

Comment: Acabo de editar, he explicado un poco como consigo obtener las relaciones

Comment: Miralo como coordenadas. Debes de recorrer los datos dos veces. La primera vez para obtener el source (eje y) y la segunda vez para obtener el target (eje x) despues compruebas con un `*ngIf` si ambos coinciden en el espacio actual. Si es asi, entonces muestras el type. Ando un poco ocupado, si nadie te ha respondido mañana te publico algo.

Comment: Vale, lo intentare de esta forma. Gracias.

Comment: No veo como hacerlo de esa forma @Legna

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente es esto lo que necesitas hacer:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th *ngFor="let dato of datos" scope="col">Evento {{dato.id}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let dato of datos">
            <th scope="row">Evento {{dato.id}}</th>

            <th *ngFor="let datoSource of datos">
        <!-- Comprobamos que el source.id sea igual al target.id para
mostrarlo. El problema esta en que no podemos hacerlo con un solo for, 
necesitamos dos y de ahi que use un dato y otro datoSource -->
                {{datoSource.source.id === dato.target.id ? dato.type : "-"   }}</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/matriz-de-datos?file=src/app/app.component.html)

---

Edicion

Segun lo que pides modifique el html y agregue unas funciones para ordenar los datos.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th *ngFor="let dato of listaDeEventos |keyvalue; let i = index" scope="col">EventoX({{i}}) {{dato.key}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let source of listaDeEventos | keyvalue, let i = index">
            <th scope="row">EventoY({{i}}) {{source.key}}</th>

            <th *ngFor="let target of listaDeEventos | keyvalue">
            
        {{obtenerCoincidenciaDeEvento(source.key, target.value)}}
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Y las nuevas funciones:

```
  obtenerCoincidenciaDeEvento(idEventoActual, eventosRelacionados) {
    // NUEVO: Si el evento no tiene algun registro retornamos
    // directamente "NO" para rellenar la matriz
    if (!eventosRelacionados) return "-";
    let eventos = eventosRelacionados.registros;

    //NUEVO: Si hay varias coincidencias
    // retornamos todas.
    let eventosEncontrados = eventos.filter(x => x.target.id == idEventoActual);
    return eventosEncontrados.length > 0
      ? eventosEncontrados.reduce((a, b) => (a += b.type), "")
      : "-";
  }
```

Y para obtener la coordenada actual :

```
obtenerCoincidenciaDeEvento(idEventoActual, eventosRelacionados) {
    let eventos = eventosRelacionados.registros;

    console.log("Eventos", eventos, "id", idEventoActual);

    let evento = eventos.find(x => x.target.id == idEventoActual);
    console.log("evento", evento);
    return evento ? evento.type : "NO";
  }
```

## Edicion

Modifique el ejemplo funcional un poco.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
      <!-- Los encabezados se generan desde la lista de eventos directamente -->
            <th *ngFor="let encabezado of eventos" scope="col">{{encabezado.name}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let ejeX of eventos">
      <!-- Las columnas igual. Aqui formamos la matriz -->
            <th scope="row"> {{ejeX.name}}</th>
      
      <!-- NUEVO: Volvemos a recorrer todos los eventos y los comparamos
      con las columnas. Usamos el id para obtener la lista de eventos ordenados -->
            <th *ngFor="let ejeY of eventos"  >

                {{obtenerCoincidenciaDeEvento(ejeX.id, listaDeEventosOrdenados[ejeY.id])}}
        </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Y modifique esto tambien:

```
obtenerCoincidenciaDeEvento(idEventoActual, eventosRelacionados) {
    // NUEVO: Si el evento no tiene algun registro retornamos
    // directamente "NO" para rellenar la matriz
    if (!eventosRelacionados) return "NO";
    let eventos = eventosRelacionados.registros;

    //NUEVO: Si hay varias coincidencias
    // retornamos todas.
    let eventosEncontrados = eventos.filter(x => x.target.id == idEventoActual);
    return eventosEncontrados.length > 0
      ? eventosEncontrados.reduce((a, b) => (a += b.type), "")
      : "NO";
  }
```

Revisa el ejemplo y me comentas.

---

De aqui viene la lista de los datos ordenados para mostrarse:

```
  listaDeEventosOrdenados = this.datos.reduce((a, b) => {
    if (!a[b.source.id]) a[b.source.id] = { registros: [] };

    a[b.source.id].registros.push({... b});
    return a;
  }, {});
```

Comment: El problema que sigo teniendo, y lo que me cuesta realizar es que si solo se usa la lista de relaciones la tabla se crea de n x n relaciones. Por eso, para las cabeceras de las columnas y las filas uso la lista de eventos, para obtener su nombre y asi tener una tabla de n x n eventos. El problema es mostrar dentro de las demas casillas los tipos de relaciones

Comment: No termino de entender muy bien tu problema. Puedes publicar una imagen desde una hoja de calculo donde se muestre el resultado que quieres?

Comment: Te he editado, espero que se entienda. PD: En la imagen en las columnas el ultimo evento es evento 3, en lugar de evento 1.

Comment: El código hace lo que pusiste en tu edición. Ciertamente, tenia un error. Lo corregí.

Comment: He editado con tu respuesta para mostrar lo que a mi me aparece

Comment: @Youshiro He agregado algunos cambios y actualizado el ejemplo. Por favor dime si estoy entendiendo bien el uso de `source` y `target` dentro del evento.

Comment: Aun no aparecen los datos como deben, con esta forma incluso me faltan eventos en las columnas. A ver tengo 2 listas, una de eventos con sus campos, y otra de relaciones con sus campos. En la de eventos solo necesito mostrar el nombre de cada uno que haya en las columnas y filas. Y el contenido debe de ser las relaciones. Pueden haber 100 eventos, y solo 3 relaciones por ejemplo, son dos diferentes. Y en relaciones se encuentra `source` y `target` que lleva el id de un evento. Si yo quiero relacionar un evento con otro, coloco cada ID en source y target, y existirá una relación nueva

Comment: Puedes poner una muestra real de la estructura de tus eventos?

Comment: Listo, tienes la pregunta editada

Comment: Que sea real, tal cual la vas a manejar. Lo que pasa es que estoy inventando datos y estructuras. Por esa razón necesito una muestra mas grande. Mencionas que puede haber 100 eventos y solo 3 relaciones de un evento. Necesito una muestra con datos reales (o por lo menos generados a mano y que sean representativos) que se acerque a esto. Por ejemplo, acotarla a 15 eventos y 3 relaciones. Te parece?

Comment: Ya lo tienes editado simulando los datos que recibo. Dime si te sirve así, y sino lo cambio

Comment: @Youshiro Hice algunos cambios. Revisalo por favor.

Comment: De donde viene esta lista? `listaDeEventosOrdenados[ejeY.id]`

Comment: Son todos los datos agrupados por el `source.id`. Asi obtenemos la relacion de datos mas facilmente.